# Changing from landscape right directly to landscape left

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, landscape, portrait

When I change directly from landscape right to landscape left there is a bug.

I have a web view and image view. In each state I have declared specific width height and position. When I am in portrait mode I have specific coordinates for the views. I also have set them for the landscape modes. When I change quickly from landscape left to landscape right all the proportions gets messed up!

I need to have access to the state when my application is in landscape right mode and directly i rotate to landscape left. i need to access it to do modifications, and if i can't how can i then force my application to pass through the portrait mode before going to the other landscape mode, Ex: 
Landscape right -> landscape left will take place as follows Landscape right -> Portrait -> landscape left.
Because if i rotate it directly from right to left i will have a bug in my software so i need to fix it.
Note that i am using a tab bar controller and i have successfully subclassed it and everything is ok.

Comment: put your code in pastebin.com and post the link in your question. Then if someone can helo they will. Also might want to reword the question a bit to make it easier to read.

Comment: Actually - post your code directly into the question, no need to add a pastebin link.

Comment: this is the link http://paste2.org/p/2379399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was with my handling of the orientation change, i should have from the beginning used :

```
 if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
```

This handed me the option to control each state. Hope this helps a future person